# Let $f(n)=\Omega(n), g(n)=O(n)$ and $h(n)=\theta(n)$ then $f(n).g(n)+h(n)$ is?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $f(n)=\Omega(n), g(n)=O(n)$ and $h(n)=\theta(n)$ then $f(n).g(n)+h(n)$ is?

**My attempt:**

Lets $f(n)=g(n)=n$, then $f(n).g(n)+h(n)=\Omega(n^2)+\theta(n)=\Omega(n^2)$

But given answer is $O(n)$. Now sure where I have have committed mistake or if I am missing something. How it can be $O(n)$?

Comment: What is the bracket notation, $[f(n).g(n)] + h(n)$? Generally, $f(n) g(n)+h(n)$ is clearer. Just in case, does the original problem look like $\lfloor f(n)g(n)\rfloor+h(n)$ or $\lceil f(n)g(n)\rceil+h(n)$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Need to improve awareness. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a fault in $f(n).g(n) = \Omega(n^2)$. Because, $g(n) = O(n)$ and you can't say $g(n)$ is $n$ or $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for example. Hence, we can't say nothing about $f(n).g(n)$. For more example:
$$g(n) = \frac{1}{n}, f(n) = n \Rightarrow f(n).g(n) = \Theta(1)$$
$$g(n) = 1, f(n) = n \Rightarrow f(n).g(n) = \Theta(n)$$
$$g(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}, f(n) = n \Rightarrow f(n).g(n) = o(1) (\text{little-o})$$ 
$$g(n) = n, f(n) = n \Rightarrow f(n).g(n) = \Theta(n^2)$$

As we don't know about $f(n).g(n)$. However, we can say $f(n).g(n) + h(n) = \Omega(n)$ as $h(n) = \Theta(n)$ and $f(n).g(n) \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks, its helpful. But given answer is $O(n)$.

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. The final answer cannot be true! Because we have some counterexample as you see. A counterexample is $f(n) = n, g(n) = n, h(n) = n$, hence $f(n).g(n) + h(n) = \Theta(n^2)$ and it is not in $O(n)$.

Comment: I don't think the asker is claiming that $f(n)g(n)=\Omega(n^2)$ for all functions $f=\Omega(n)$ and $g=O(n)$. Rather, they're just saying that $f(n)=g(n)=n$ gives a counterexample to the "official" answer of $O(n)$.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, I was giving counterexample. But now I think its $\Omega(n)$ precisely as the answer explained. Right?

Comment: @Mr.Sigma. $\Omega(n)$ seems to be correct, yes.